# Getting exit code 0x80131029, when running powershell through vmware API

Tags: powershell, remote-access, vsphere, vmware-tools

I am getting exit code as 0x80131029 when running powershell through VMware API.

[image]

Is there anyway I can find out the reason for this exit code through windows log or any other method?

Following cmdlets are being used:

Get-WMIObject

Get-ItemProperty

Get-CimInstance

Answer (score 2):

With below function you can get (most of) the descriptions for these HRESULT values:

```
function Resolve-HResult {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [int32[]]$HResult
    )

    Process {
        foreach ($hr in $HResult) {
            $comEx = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetExceptionForHR($hr)
            if ($comEx) {
                $comEx.Message
            }
            else {
                Write-Error "$hr doesn't correspond to a known HResult"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your case:

```
Resolve-HResult 0x80131029
```

returns

> ```
> Process exited due to Timeout escalation.
> ```

Hope that helps

Comment: This I new, it is available online also. But what is the root cause for this? I mean it is coming as a transient error. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Is there any way to find the root cause of this error.

Comment: @DharmenderLodhi Since you didn't post any code, there is no telling why the timeouts sometimes happen.

Comment: I have edited the question which are being used while executing the script. But strange thing is, even if I execute script with "exit 0;" . I am getting this exitcode, I am guessing even the powershell isn't starting.